# blackberry file uploading to server

Tags: blackberry, http-headers, http-post

I am trying to upload file to server and for that I try so many different codes but I can't get success.

In this code connection is created successfully, but at the time of reading file and posting data to server by creating header...

```java
class ConnectionThread extends Thread
{
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;
    String boundary =  "*****";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 2*1024*1024;
    DataInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    public void run()
    {  
        try {          
          ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
          ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
          connDesc = connFact.getConnection("http://www.myserver/upload.php");

          if (connDesc != null)
          {
              HttpConnection conn;
              conn = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection();

              conn.setRequestMethod(conn.POST);

              conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
              conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
              conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);


              outputStream = new DataOutputStream( conn.openDataOutputStream() );
              outputStream.writeChars(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
              outputStream.writeChars("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + "files:///SDCard/bb.txt" +"\"" + lineEnd);
              outputStream.writeChars(lineEnd); 

              bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
              bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
              buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

              // Read file
              FileConnection fis=(FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/bb.txt");

              InputStream inputStream = fis.openInputStream();

              ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              int buffersize=1024*1024;
              byte[] buffer=new byte[buffersize];
              int length=0;
              while((length=inputStream.read(buffer))!=-1)
              {
                   bos.write(buffer,0,length);
              }
              byte[] imagedata=bos.toByteArray();

              outputStream.write(imagedata);                 

              outputStream.writeChars(lineEnd);
              outputStream.writeChars(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

              // Responses from the server (code and message)
              int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
              final String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();                    

              fileInputStream.close();
              outputStream.flush();
              outputStream.close();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

plz somebody help... thanks in advance..

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: when you're trying to debug code that doesn't work, it's always a bad idea to have an exception catch handler that just does nothing, and quietly traps the exception. at the very least, do `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace() }`. see if you are getting an exception. then, if you are, post that along with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This link,
This code is support to upload file on Server using multi part . 
it can also work on blackberry , With some modifications needed.

```
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME
```